# Building XML parser in Java without existing parser implementations

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

Is there a decent way to create a primitive XML parser in Java without using Jackson, JDK and Document Builder implementations? How theoretically this should look like?

For example, implement parsing of basic element definition syntax:

```
<root>
<first></first>
<second></second>
</root>
```

Implement pretty printing of a parsed element tree: each element on a separate
line, nested elements indented by 4 spaces and to do basic escaping of '<' and '>' symbols through < and > when
parsing:

```
<escaped&lt;&gt;></escaped&lt;&gt;>
```

Then, implement parsing inline empty elements:

```
<root>
<empty/>
</root>
```

Comment: Is there a decent way to create a primitive XML parser in Java? Sure there is. But I suspect that you don't have the skills to do it, because if you did, you wouldn't be asking the question. Techniques for parsing (e.g. top down recursive descent, bottom-up, finite state automata etc) are covered in undergraduate computer science courses, and you shouldn't attempt it without reading up on the theory first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build a recursive descent parser using a tokenizer based on compiled regular expressions (while it is impossible to *parse* XML using regular expressions, there isn't anything wrong with using regular expressions for XML tokenization).

I'd design the tokenizer interface roughly as follows (using a Scanner internally):

```
class XmlTokenizer {
  String getCurrentText();
  boolean tryConsumeStartTagStart();
  boolean tryConsumeAttributeName();
  boolean tryConsumeText();
  ...
```

The parser then can try the token types valid at the current position and obtain the corresponding text (e.g. the element or attribute name) using the getCurrentText() method.

For instance, content parsing would look as follows:

```
void parseNodeContent(Node node) {
  while (true) {
    if (tokenizer.tryConsumeText()) {
      node.appendText(getCurrentText());
    } else if (tryConsumeStartTagStart()) {
      node.append(parseElement());
    } else if

      ...  // processing instructions, entity references

    } else {
      // Let the caller deal with all the rest, including errors.
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Element parsing might look like this:

```
// Precondition: on element start
// Postcondition: on element end
Element parseElement() {
  Element result = new Element(tokenizer.getCurrentText());
  while (tryConsumeAttributeName()) {
    String attributeName = tokenizer.getCurrentText();

    ... // attribute value parsing

  }
  if (!tokenizer.tryConsumeStartTagEndSelfClosing()) {
    if (!tokenizer.tryConsumeStartTagEnd()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Invalid start tag end");
    }
    parseContent(result);
    if (!tokenizer.tryConsumeEndTag(result.name())) {
      throw new RuntimeException("End tag missing for " +result.name());
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I have picked up the `tryConsumeXxx()` style from Kenton Varla's protocol buffer definition parser and I found it quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

First step is quite clear you need to tokenize XML. After that step you have list of of tokens - like tag, attributes, values, and so on.

Next step depends on implementation. If you mentioned DOM, then whole list has to be processed. So '<' opens tag creation, then name comes, after that possible list of params til '>'. Then sub notes has to be build into sub tree of this particular node. Note that you need to replace things like & into &.

For basic processing that should be OK. Other topics includes namespaces, and validations...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and there are probably a dozen different ways to do it. XML lends itself to recursive descent parsing, for example. Examined at any level, an XML file has the basic structure

```
<tag1>something</tag1><tag2>something</tag2>...
```

where the "something" has itself the same structure as the overall file. The "something" may be empty, and the tag itself might be collapsed into `<tag/>` -- these cases have to be looked for.

The parser looks for lists of patterns of the form `<tag>something</tag>` and, if the "something" turns out to start with another `<tag>`, it calls itself recursively to parse this new section. The recursion completes when all the sections of the document have been explorered to the bottom. On each new recursive call we create an instance of a class to hold the data, and a recursive tree of these instances gets built up, rather like a DOM model.

A skilled parser designer would be able to make this whole thing way more efficient and, of course, you'd have to deal with parsing out the namespace, attributes, etc. But implementing something like this using a recursive parser is an interesting exercise.